# Can I have one self signed SSL certificate with alternate names for two different domains

Tags: ssl-certificate

I need one self signed certificate to cover multiple URLs, which could be represented by the following:

```
*.foo.com
*.faa.fii.bar.com
```

Using alternate names I managed to create such a certificate, but I get a certificate error from the browser when accessing

```
bla.foo.com
```

I created another certificate for  ****.faa.fii.bar.com***, without ****.foo.com***.  This time I gave alternate names for several other sites, but all belonging to bar.com.
So the common name was

```
*.faa.fii.bar.com
```

and alternate names were:

```
*.fii.bar.com
*.bar.com
*.fee.bar.com
```

This worked fine for any url which matches these patterns, so `a.fii.bar.com` or `a.bar.com` worked with the certificate.  But if I add `*.foo.com`, which looks just like `*.bar.com`, then urls such as `a.foo.com` are not accepted, while `a.bar.com` is accepted.
How is this limitation defined?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that `*` in a certificate only matches a single sub-part of the fully-qualified name.  So `*.example.com` matches `a.example.com` and `xyzzy.example.com`, but not `foo.bar.example.com`.  To match further levels of FQDN, you need to add more asterisks, leading to certificates that have a great many `subjectAltName` entries, like:

```
*.example.com
*.*.example.com
*.*.*.example.com
```

And so on.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my example.  In my case the CN was `*.a.example.com` . If I gave an alternate name `*.b.example.com` then a url such as `z.b.example.com` worked fine.  But if I added an alternate name such as `*.b.somethingelse.com`, then a url such as `z.b.somethingelse.com` gave an error.

Comment: Then you were doing it wrong.  Perhaps forgetting the `dns:` at the beginning of the `subjectAltName` entry.

Comment: You are right. I was indeed doing it wrong. I now got this to work, and its very helpful.  How about a wildcard in the middle - e.g. `a.*.example.com` .  Could that work?  Could I then use a URL such as `a.b.example.com`?